# What made the difference

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties

What made the difference

`@property (strong, nonatomic) and @property (nonatomic, strong)`  in ios.

i will define iboutlet for example uilabel like this

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
```

and i see many time in this site

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* str;
```

What is the difference between the two property.

Comment: There is no any logical difference between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no differences in the logic. They represent the same thing but with different order.

Usually in IBOutlets you have `@property (weak, nonatomic)` because it is auto generated when you ctrl+drag from interface builder.

However, most people prefer the second form because the "nonatomic" is used in most of the cases **in ios** and therefore it is easily ignored.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. But in apple sample codes and most frequently we use :

```
@property (nonatomic, strong)
```